# selecting item in loop by ID

Tags: jquery, loops

jQuery

```
for (i = 0; i <= globalStore.data.length;i++ ) {
```

**/*confusion starts*/**

```
 $(".morning").each(function() {
                //getting id for each div of class 'morning'
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

**/*but all this css changing is done for div with class 'morning' without matching the id*/**

```
             $(this).children("span").css("background-color","#ff0");

                $(this).children("span").each(function() {
                if(globalStore.data[i].morning.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
                });

            });
```

**/*confusion ends*/**

```
 <div class='morning' id='mor_"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"'>Morning: <span class='Mon'>M </span><span class='Tue'>T </span><span class='Wed'>W </span><span class='Thrs'>T </span><span class='Fri'>F </span><span class='Sat'>S </span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div>

}
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
  $(".morning").each(function() {

           var ID = $(this).attr("id");
```

**/* check and change per id */**

```
 $(this ID).children("span").each(function() {
            if(globalStore.data[i].morning.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

              $(this).css("color","#26F525");

            }
});
```

Comment: you are storing array length in `len`, but looping through array with `k` as upper limit, is this correct?

Comment: @nemesis_sun, yes that's right. If I replace k with len then it won't color any of the results

Comment: you should also put `data` as local variable inside `colorMe`, and reset it every time you call `colorMe` i.e `for(data=0;data < len;data++)`

Comment: @nemesis_sun, you mean I should remove the var data = 0; outside colorMe and do like this: for(var data;data < k;data++)

Comment: @nemesis_sun, tried but doesn't color any result. I know there's something wrong in my code as everytime I change the order of any variable in the function ,it doesn't color